# How do I tell Windsor to error if it can't resolve a property?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

Say I have the following classes

```
    public class TestA
    {
        public string Blah { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestB
    {
        public TestA Testing { get; set; }
    }
```

So say I want Windsor to give me an instance of `TestB`, but I also want it to use property injection to instantiate the `TestB.Testing` property.  This part is easy, but I need a way to know if the Windsor registration for `TestA` is removed.

Is there any way to mark the `Testing` property so that Windsor knows that `TestA` is a dependency of `TestB`, and thus should error out if it can't resolve the `Testing` property?  I do not want to use the `TestB` constructor, as I am looking at ways to lower constructor bloat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is a mandatory dependency it should go into the constructor period. Otherwise you're allowing to instantiate an invalid component, and this has nothing to do with Windsor or IoC.

"Constructor bloat" can sometimes be a sign that the code needs to be refactored, it may have acquired too many responsibilities.

EDIT: if you **really** know what you're doing you can "manually" change dependencies as optional or mandatory using a [component model contributor](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.ComponentModel-construction-contributors.ashx). I'd argue that this should only be used for code that you can't control, almost never for your own code.

Comment: The constructor bloat is mostly coming from Asp.NET MVC controllers, as the different actions a controller uses different service classes.  It also comes from business actions requiring multiple queries to run.  For example, if I am editing an entity I need to make sure the entity actually exists in the db, I need to make sure I am authorized to edit this entity, etc...  Each of these queries is a separate service class, and I don't see a problem where one may depend on another (especially when I am trying to keep logic in central locations)

Comment: I'd wrap those dependencies in some `Context` class, especially if they are often used together, rather than try to hide them.

Comment: @KallDrexx: it seems it's time to move some of those business concerns from controllers into a proper business layer.

Comment: That's not the issue Mauricio, that's already done.  For example in my CompanyController, my Add action's only code calls the `CreateCompanyCommand` class, my Edit action's only code calls the `EditCompanyCommand` class, my Details action's only code calls the `CompanyByIdQuery` class, etc...  The problem is each of these classes have to be instantiated by IoC, and thus bloat the controller's constructor

Comment: @driushkin, do you mean to wrap all the dependencies into a single class, and put that class in the controller's constructor?  If so that's an interesting idea, but that still just moves the constructor bloat from the controller to the context classes, unless I am misunderstanding something.

Comment: @KallDrexx: ok, but you still need to refactor your code instead of trying to work around a symptom...

Comment: @KallDrexx: I recommend creating a new question with more information about your particular case, so people can give you more specific answers.

Comment: Well regardless, I still am interested in the answer to this question because property injection stands to be extremely error prone if you can't have Windsor error on failed property injection when it's expected.

Comment: @KallDrexx yep, that's the idea. It will only solve something if there are many places (eg, controllers) where you are passing the same list of dependencies.

Comment: @KallDrexx: properties are considered *optional* dependencies by Windsor. If an optional dependency isn't satisfied, it can't be considered an error. Just like you can instantiate an object without setting any properties, but you can't instantiate an object if you try to skip any constructor parameters. That's the rationale.

Comment: Your logic makes sense, I guess I just don't see a good scenario for optional dependency.  I'll have to think about the method you posted but I don't think the bloated constructors is a code smell, it's directly caused by me splitting my business logic out into separate units to prevent repeating code.  The only way to lower constructor bloat otherwise is to make my service classes fat with a lot of independent query methods and actions, and I don't particularly like that idea.

Comment: @KallDrexx: the typical optional dependency is a logger. You can always operate without logging. If you don't think a bloated constructor is a code smell in your case, then don't refactor (seriously). These are just guidelines, rules of thumb, but only you know what's best for your project at any time.

Comment: Oh the logger idea makes sense.  Thanks for being patient :)